# ASP.Net MVC Razor View Showing Error Lines

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I see error lines in my razor views.

[image: Screenshot of the error]

However, my application runs fine without any errors.

Comment: Please take a look at [mcve] and edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

Add a semicolon at the end of the top line (line 1). 
Also what does “Model” refer to on line 5?

Comment: Adding a semicolon does not make any difference. That is how I see error lines in all my razor views, meanwhile the application is working fine. The only reason I get tired about this is that I don't get inteliscence.

Comment: Intellisense is a bit hit and miss in Razor views. If it's working fine, and there are no compilation errors (i.e. the code does what you want it to with no problems) then I'd probably just ignore them. I do have the same issue every now and again.

Answer (score 0):

If your app runs ok then there isn't any error. It happens all the time and it is related to the intelliSense that might get stuck at some point. If you restart your visual studio and maybe clean-build the lines will be lost.